# Remove whats common to both lists

Tags: java

How can I remove whats common to both lists based on an object attribute. Below I am trying to remove all values from testList2 that contain the same str1 parameter as testList1.

I think I can override the equals method in the class that is being compared as equals method is used under the hood when using removeAll ?

testList1 & testList2 are of type ArrayList and both contain a List of Test objects.

```
testList1.removeAll(testList2);

public class Test{

    private String str1;
    private String str2;

    public Test(String str1 , String str2){
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){

        Test t = (Test)o;
        return this.getStr1().equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStr2());

    }
}
```

Comment: What class is `testList1` (e.g. `ArrayList`,  `LinkedList`, ...)?

Comment: @Thomas testList1 & testList2 are of type ArrayList

Comment: Shouldn't `equals()` compare **`this`** object to the object passed as parameter? Why your `equals()` method compares `str1` of the parameter to `str2` of the parameter?

Comment: You should replace your return line with this: `return o != null && o.getStr1().equals(this.getStr1());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, overriding `equals(...)` should work with `removeAll(...)`, since `ArrayList` will use that for equality checks.

Under the hood, the `removeAll(...)` method in `AbstractCollection` (which is a super class of `ArrayList`) will call `contains(entry)` on the collection that is passed to `removeAll(...)`. `contains(...)` in `ArrayList` will then get the index of the element using `indexOf(...)` which in turn loops through all elements and calls `equals(...)` on those.

That said, it becomes obvious that the `removeAll()` implementation using lists has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity (loop through the source list and for each entry loop through the parameter list) which might get quite slow for bigger lists.

Thus you might want to pass a set of the objects that you want removed to `removeAll(...)`. This would result in O(n * log(n)) complexity (the loop over the source list remains, but the `contains` call on a set is O(log(n)) only).

Answer (score 1):

If you want all objects from both lists without repeated ones (at least that was what I understood before your edits):

```
Set<Test> both = new HashSet<Test>();
both.addAll(testList1);
both.addAll(testList2);
//and if you really need to use a List instead of a Set
List<Test> result = new ArrayList<Test>(both);
```

Of course, you'll still have to override `equals()` so the collections can understand what you mean by it.

Comment: You should add some words to say how this relates to the question.

Comment: a set doesn't allow duplicates, so if you added both of the arraylists to the set, it will only take the unique ones

Answer (score 1):

First of all `equals()` should determine whether two objects are *logically equal*. If these objects are logically equal when their `str1` fields are equal then you may go with equals and use methods defined for the collections. In this case `equals()` contract (defined in the java.lang.Object) is worth reading.

If I were working with your code I would prefer if you solve your problem with iteration instead of defining incorrect `equals()` method (Warning: not tested code):

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<String>(listOne.size());
for(Test t : listOne){
   strings.add(t.getStr1());
}

Iterator<Test> it = listTwo.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
  Test t = it.next();
  if(strings.contains(t.getStr1())
     it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think I can override the equals method in the class that is being compared as equals method is used under the hood when using removeAll ?

```
// you need to compare the current values to the values in t
public boolean equals(Object o){
    Test t = (Test)o;
    return t.getStr1().equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStr1())
          && t.getStr2().equalsIgnoreCase(t.getStr2());
}
```

I would also make the fields final if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If str1 is present in testList1 & testList2, you want to remove it from both Lists, right!

```
// Iterate till all elements
for (int i=0; i < testList.size()-1; i++) {
   Test t1 = testList1.get(i);  // Get element i of TestList1 Arr
   Test t2 = testList2.get(i);  // Get element i of TestList2 Arr

   // If t1 & t2 both contains same values in str1 & str2 
    if (t1.equuals(str1) && t2.equals(str1) ) {
       // Remove the elements from list
       testList1.remove(i);
       testlist2.remove(i);
    }
}
```

If you want to override equals in Test object

```
  // This will comapre current instance and the passed instance
  public boolean equals(String toCompare, Test obj) {
    return (this.equals(toComare) && obj.equals(toComapre));
  }
```

Hope this helps you. Use whichever is convinient to you, both will work.